# Facebook Share Button's title, how to change?

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook share link, but I want to change its title, instead of using the original title in that page,

e.g.

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com&t=Yahoo
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also am looking how to do this. Seems facebook cache's the title/description and image shared with the inital share.. per url.. The only workaround I know is to make a new URL or append a random query string (ie  ?random=12312321) to the url and share it if you changed something that points to the same resource.

Also you can use the facebook  Debugger Tool to reset the Title/description that is pulled into facebook:  here is a link to the tool:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug